# Is there any way to get notified when battery is full?

Tags: notification, power-management

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on a laptop, I was wondering if there is a way to get notified when the battery become full.

Comment: This can be done by running a script. But first i need to know which type of battery you are using.Open terminal.type `ls /proc/acpi/battery/`. What is the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was present on old gnome2, but mising from latest gnome.Gnome power manager is supposed to give notification when battery is full, but it doesn't(It could be a bug). I couldn't find any option with dconf either.To me it appears that the only way to achieve this through a cron job which regulary checks whether battery is full or not.

First open terminal & type `ls /proc/acpi/battery/.` In my case, the output is ***C241***. Your could be different(generally batt0 ot batt1).Also check the type of ac adapter,`ls /proc/acpi/ac_adapter`. Its ***C240*** for me. Open gedit & copy the following script.

**Remember to replace C241 & C240 with your battery type & ac adapter.**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/.scripts
notification=$(grep 'notification:' notification|awk '{print $2}')

cd /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/C240;
power=$(grep 'state:' state|awk '{print $2}')
s1="$power"

s2="charged"
s3="on-line"
s4="on"

export DISPLAY=:0

if [ "$s1" = "on-line" ]; then
  cd /proc/acpi/battery/C241;
  state=$(grep 'charging state:' state|awk '{print $3}')
  if [ $state = $s2 ] && [ "$notification" = "$s4" ];
    then
            notify-send  --urgency=critical "Power Manager" "battery is full" -i battery_full
            echo "notification: off" >~/.scripts/notification

    fi

else
  if [ $notification != "on" ]; then
    echo "notification: on" >~/.scripts/notification
  fi
fi
```

save the file as **batteryfull.sh** at ~/.scripts (or anywhere you like).
Make the file executable `chmod a+x batteryfull.sh`.

On terminal type `echo "notification: on" >~/.scripts/notification`. Also add the same line at the end of your ~/.profile.

Install gnome-schedule (`sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule`).Launch it, choose new task & select "a task that launches recuurently". On command section put full path of the script file.In my case its ~/.scripts/batteryfull.sh.You can set corn-job duration every min or every 5 min.click apply.You can check running jobs by typing `crontab -l` in terminal.

[image: gnome-schedule]

You can run this script at every boot by adding gnome-schedule as a startup application(may not be required in your case).

Note: This is probably not the perfect way to do this, but it works.So far this much i can do with my little knowledge with bash scripting.I will improve the script if i find something better.

Comment: Try setting an envorinment variable(or even a file) when the battery is full, and when the battery starts depleting, reset it so that the notification can be retriggered when the battery is full again.

Comment: Initially that was my plan.I made system-wide variable like "export NOTIFICATION=on" & added to ~/.profile.But couldn't able to change(set /unset) that variable from bash script. Finally I created a separate file &  read the data from there.

Comment: thank you, it works after adding the notification file using `echo "notification: on" >~/.scripts/notification`