# How to make the laptop beep when battery is fully charged

Tags: laptop, notification

I read about getting the laptop beeping when the battery charging is complete [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170531/how-can-i-get-notification-when-my-laptop-battery-gets-fully-charged/402618#402618).

But I'm confused with the answer (and I didn't know yet, how to ask directly to a user).

Where can I find the file "return0whencharging.sh".. ?

Or I must create it by my self? If so, is there any particular folder where I should save the file?

Comment: Better try this script which shows a notification. http://askubuntu.com/questions/150302/is-there-any-way-to-get-notified-when-battery-is-full. You can modify it to make a sound.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are following the suggestion at [How can I get notification when my laptop battery gets fully charged?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170531/how-can-i-get-notification-when-my-laptop-battery-gets-fully-charged)

Create the file named **return0whencharging.sh** with a text editor program, so you could write this to a brand new file of that name, located in your path (a directory such as /usr/local/sbin ). For example, from within a terminal window, enter this line:

```
sudo nano /usr/local/sbin/return0whencharging.sh
```

which will put that script where it will be automagically found when desired.